# Powershell internet explorer COM object is able to click in shell, but not in script

Tags: powershell

I am able to successfully login to the webpage by running the selection of code, but I am unable to run it from the script itself.

Current Powershell ISE settings:

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy
'Unrestricted'
```

Login Script:

```
$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("userName").value = $LoginName
$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("password").value = $LoginPassword
$submit = $ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByName("submit").item(0)
#issues seem to occur at this point
$submit.Click()
```

No errors appear to show when running the code.

Comment: How are you defining `$ie`?  What is your `$ErrorActionPreference`?

Comment: `$ie = new-object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application";
$ie.Visible = $true`

Comment: `$ErrorActionPreference` = `Continue`

Comment: Have you tried clicking buttons on different sites?  Is `$submit` valid?

Comment: No, I had not thought of that. The submit feature seems to work when it is removed from the whole script and put into a new script. It seems to be something with the order I had the login placed at in the script. Moving it up to the top of the entire script I was working on seemed to resolve the problem...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Original code is working. Code block works in another saved PS1 file. Had to re-arrange code inside original script to get it to function correctly.